# JTable, refreshing rowData vector in static context

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i've declared a JTable (inside a class extended JPanel constructor) such as

```
data_table = new JTable(info, header) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        //disable table editing
        return false;
    }
};
```

where info and column are declared

```
static String[][] info = new String[row][cols];
static String[] header = {"h1", "h2", "h3"};
```

Now i need to update, when some events occours, the table content by invoke a static method. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i don't have a tableModel, i've a matrix of string

All tables use a TableModel. When you create the table the matrix of Strings is used by the TableModel.

To update your data you do something like:

```
table.setValueAt(...);
```

This will cause the model to be updated and the model will tell the table to repaint itself.

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information about tables.

Also, you should NOT be using static variables or method. If you are then you program is poorly designed. Again read the tutorial for a better example of how to structure your code.

Comment: sorry, i'm not explain my problem so well. I don't need to modify ad existing data row, but i need to "append" some new rows to JTable.

Comment: Use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel`.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to notify your JTable about changes of your data, call a method on your tablemodel that will update the data and call `fireTableDataChanged()`

Its is a good practice to use a JTableModel to maintain your data inside the JTable.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

And that is your tablemodel that will fire the `fireTableDataChanged()` when value will change.

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[] columnNames = ...//same as before...
    private Object[][] data = ...//same as before...

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * editable.
     */
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
        //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
        if (col < 2) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * data can change.
     */
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: -1, you should not use tableModel.fireXXX methods directly. The fireXXX methods should only be invoked by the TableModel itself.

Comment: i don't have a tableModel, i've a matrix of string.

Comment: @giozh you _must_ have a tableModel, that's the only way to correctly setup a JTable with data